# H1 tag with a class inherits properties of h1

Tags: html, css

Recently I was practicing some basics of CSS and while I was on Class Selectors I found some doubts which are confusing me.

I have declared some style properties of a H1 tag and I also have declared some style properties of a H1 tag with a class. When I viewed the result on my web browser then I found that my H1 tag with a class was inheriting one property of my H1 tag. This is the thing which is confusing. How can a tag with class inherit properties of same tag but without a class. If so then how? And if I don't want to inherit the properties of the other tag then how can I do that?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*styling for h1 tag.*/
h1
{
text-align:center;
color:yellow;
}
h1.class1
{
color:blue;
font-size:30px;
}
h2.class1
{
color:purple;
font-size:25px;
}
h3.class1
{
color:red;
font-size:15px;
}
</style>
<body>
<h1>C.S.S. Class Selector with different tags.</h1>
<hr>
<p>In this example you will see different level of headings with different styles but with same class.</p>
<h1 class="class1">
I am a H1 heading and I have class1 as a class.
</h1>
<h2 class="class1">
I am a H2 heading and I also have class1 as a class.
</h2>
<h3 class="class1">
I am a H3 heading and I also have class1 as a class.
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is normal CSS behaviour. You can override the properties though.

Comment: How? Will you please elaborate this.

Comment: Your h1 styles will affect all h1s. The only exception would be if the class contained styles that conflict with the h1 styles—in which case, they would override them.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is cascading, meaning what you declare first is what the element will inherit until another declaration further down the line overrides this. For example,

```
h1 {
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
}
```

With this, all `<h1>`'s will have the font color red and will be centrally aligned. If you gave a particular `<h1>` a class, you can override the above by delcaring it as follows:

```
h1.class1 {
    text-align: right;
    color: blue;
}
```

This means that `<h1>`'s with the class `class1` WILL NOT be centrally aligned or red, they'll be right aligned and blue.

If you were to leave out the text-align from the `class1` declaration, the `h1`'s which have `class1` as a class, will inherit the `h1` element's declaration, so they'll be centrally aligned. You have to override what was declared first for it to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

The h1 is still a h1-tag, whether or not it has a class.

If it has a class, then it is just a bit different than the ones without, so in your case, you need to write the CSS like this, for the h1 with a class:

```
h1.class1
{
color:blue;
font-size:30px;
text-align:left;
}
```

Or, you can write:

```
h1.class1
{
color:blue;
font-size:30px;
text-align:inherit;
}
```

To make the h1 with a class, float the same way as the other text.

Answer (score 0):

U have to overwrite css by using the h1 class="class1", because if u use the .h1 it will take same css for all the h1 in the tag.